# Tableview animation left to right with segment control

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableview with 1 section and a segment control in the header of that tableview. After I change the segment in the header of the tableview, I want the tableview to move to the left and another tableview with the new data related to the info in the selected index of the segment control to come in from the right. This should be an animation. I have tried these 4 things but they all have there own issues. The biggest two issues is that I don't want to animate the section headers and the data sets are different. The section header should always just remain the same so `reloadSections` does not work. `reloadRows` has the perfect animation that I am looking for but it doesn't work because the number of rows are different for the two sets of data. So it crashes when it is used.

The solution needs to work when there is no data in the table and it reloads for the first time after the data is fetched. Or it reloads to no rows being in the table and an empty state screen is displayed.

```
//1
UIView.animate(withDuration0.7, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
    self.mainTableView.reloadData()
}, completion: {})

//2
self.mainTableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .right)

//3
self.mainTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexpaths], with: .right)

//4
self.mainTableView.beginUpdates()
self.mainTableView.insertRows(at: [indexpaths], with: .right)
self.mainTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexpaths], with: .right)
self.mainTableView.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just change the data source within same tableView, and put the segment as a view upon the tableView instead of header.

Comment: So I am using large titles for the nav bar so if I put the header on top things get really messed up. Even if I change the data source the thing listed above don’t work.